# Count the number of non-scalar items in a cell array

Tags: matlab, permutation, cell-array

I have a cell `c` of some (quite large) particular permutations of 1:10, some of which are repeated. How can I count the number of occurrences of each permutation?

The output should be easily accessible for later use e.g. I can do something like

```
c([1 2 5 4 3 7 8 9 6 10]) = 20
```

After a bit of searching, there is `histcounts` but it seems to apply only for an array of doubles. I also don't want to use `for` because there are so many different permutations.

Comment: `for` loops aren't inherently slow, MATLAB optimises them to be pretty quick. It would be useful if you could illustrate your expected behaviour with a `for` loop structure, then vectorising it may be something we can quickly help with (if needed, unless it's quick enough!).

Answer (score 1):

Let's define example data `c` with `N` permutations of `1:M` :

```
N = 1e5;
M = 10;
c = cell(1,N);
for n = 1:N
  c{n} = randperm(M);
end
```

Then

```
[unique_perms,~,w] = unique(vertcat(c{:}), 'rows');
count_perms = accumarray(w,1);
```

gives an `M`-column matrix `unique_perms` where each row is a unique permutation from `c`, and a column vector `count_perms` with the corresponding numbers of occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to define an anonymous function to count certain permutation in cell `c`:

```
permCount = @(perm, c) sum(cellfun(@(x) isequal(x, perm), c));
```

For a permutation in your questioon:

```
permCount([1 2 5 4 3 7 8 9 6 10], c)
```

will give its count in `c`

If you prefer, you can make sure cell `c` exists before you define the anonymous function. Then you can leave it out as input:

```
c = @(perm) sum(cellfun(@(x) isequal(x, perm), c)); % cell c must exist
c([1 2 5 4 3 7 8 9 6 10]) % gives the count
```

This gives exactly what you wrote, but it is better to use different name for the anonymous function to avoid confusion.